# Find Maximum Positive Index

Tags: java, arrays

You are given an array A. We define a term Positive difference index as the count of elements between the two indexes i and j (both inclusive) such that `i<j` and `A[i]<A[j]`.
Now for the given array, you have to find the maximum positive difference index. It is assured that the test case will be valid such that there exists an answer.

**Input format**

First line : T i.e Number of test cases.
For each test case :
First line : N
Second line : N space separated integers denoting the element of the array.

**Output format**

Print the answer to each test case in a separate line and it is given that answer always exists.

Sample Input 
1
6
5 3 2 1 1 4

Sample Output 
5

Explanation 
let i=2 and j=6 then `A[i]<A[j]` and total elements between them is 5 so the maximum answer that can be achieved is 5.

I had tried to find maximun number from an array and minimum number from array such that `A[i]<A[j]`. With sample input it worked but for when I submitted the question on hackerearth it displayed none test cases were passed. Can anyone please me help to understand the question and program?

Below program I have written

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            String line = br.readLine();
            int totalTest = Integer.parseInt(line);
            for(int i=0;i<totalTest;i++) {
                line = br.readLine();
                int totalElements = Integer.parseInt(line);
                line = br.readLine();
                String strArr[] = line.split(" ");
                int elements[] = new int[strArr.length];
                for(int j=0;j<strArr.length;j++) {
                    elements[j] = Integer.parseInt(strArr[j]);
                }

                System.out.println(findMaximumPositiveIndex(elements));
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            if(br!=null)
                br.close();
        }
    }

    public static int findMaximumPositiveIndex(int[] arr) {
        int max=arr[0];
        int maxIndex = 0;
        int minIndex=arr[0];
        int min=0;

        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if( min==0 ) {
                min = arr[i];
                minIndex=i;
            }
            if(arr[i] < min) {
                min = arr[i];
                minIndex = i;
            }
            if(arr[i] > max) {
                max = arr[i];
                maxIndex = i;
            }
        }

        return (max - min) + 1;

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are trying? Do you get the sample output, if so you have at least one test which passes.

Comment: Really you expect us to solve your ACM questions??

Comment: @Saeed.At I am not expecting you to solve the problem. I just needed help to understand the problem statement. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum and minimum values from the array, in most cases they won’t help you. So don’t find those. In the example in the question the maximum value is 5 and the minimum is 1. Neither of those two values are involved in calculating the output. Instead the values 3 and 4 are because they are the farthest apart values that fulfil the condition A[i] < A[j]. The output should be 5 because the part of the array `3 2 1 1 4` has length 5. Or “the count of elements between the two indexes i and j (both inclusive)”, as the challenge puts it.

Instead you find the output from the min and max values as (5 – 1) + 1 = 5 (I think; I haven’t studied your code thoroughly). Coincidentally you hit the correct output in this single case. You haven’t done it correctly.

Other examples:

- For 2 1 2 1 2 1 the answer is 4 because the part 1 2 1 2 has length 4 and 1 < 2.
- For 40 90 10 60 the answer is 4 too because 40 90 10 60 has 4 elements in it and 40 < 60.

I understood that you asked for help understanding the problem, not for solving it, so I am happy to leave that pleasure to yourself.

Comment: Thanks Ole. I modified the code. Thanks for helping to understand the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for helping to understand the problem statement.

I have modified the code

```
public static int findMaximumPositiveIndex(int[] arr) {
    int min=arr[0],max=arr[0],minIndex=0,maxIndex=0;
    int maximumIndex = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        min = arr[i];
        minIndex=i;
        boolean isMaxPresent = false;
        for(int j=i;j<arr.length;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j] > min){
                max = arr[j];
                maxIndex = j;
                isMaxPresent = true;
            }
        }
        if(maximumIndex < ((maxIndex - minIndex) +1) )
            maximumIndex = (maxIndex - minIndex) + 1;
    }
    return maximumIndex;

}
```

which fulfills all the test cases. Thanks

Comment: I tried to see if I could find any further bugs. I cannot.